# Laravel 5.1- Route Middleware doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having a problem with the following error: `Error:ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

My code is as follows:

**--> CheckSession.php middleware**

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {     
     if ($request->session()->has('email')){ return $next($request); }
     else{return redirect('/crm');}
    }
```

**--> routes.php**

```
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckSession;

Route::get('testamacli', function () {
   return view('blank');    
})->middleware('session');
```

**-->Kernel.php**

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'session' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSession::class,
    ];
```

Comment: try `if(session()->has('email'))`

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work". Do you get a 500 error? do you get a 200 response but no body? do you see anything in the logs? have you added debugging statements to your code that don't turn up in the logs? The idea on Stackoverflow is that you read [ask] to pose an answerable question

Comment: if(session()->has('email')) I tried. But not enough for working  @ChristopheHubert

Comment: In log file  @JoSSte

#21 /home/lysstr603/public_html/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

-->index.php (line 54)
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

Comment: I lost you at `i tried, but not enough for working`, that is really confusing.
Update your `question` by responding to the question: Do you get a 500 error? do you get a 200 response but no body?
Maybe a screenshot will help

Comment: @UnderDog Error:ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: use middleware in  __construct()  method  ...

Answer (score 0):

use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;

I have added this class in Middleware and software is started to work. :) Thank you for answering to me.

Comment: I have the feeling that you are using a very old version of Laravel. Open your composer.json and look for laravel/framework. If the version there is older than 5.8 you have 2 options: 1) Start from scratch with Laravel 6 or 7. 2) upgrade to Laravel 5.8 (for now). If your version is older than 5.3 start from scratch for sure.